# xUnit, Moq with UnitOfWork and general repository

Tags: repository, moq, xunit, unit-of-work

I tried a lot of examples but I do not get the good response.
The ReportUpload method creates some Report entity based on the list from ExcelManager list
and adds them to the Reports DbSet.
My goal would be to read out the added entities from the mocked DbSet and assert them.
How can I pass the mocked DbContext and Dbset into UnitOfWork, please?

**GeneralRepository.cs**

```
public class GeneralRepository<TContext, TEntity> : IGeneralRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
    where TContext : DbContext
{
    protected readonly TContext _context;
    protected readonly DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public GeneralRepository(TContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        dbSet = _context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public async Task AddAsync(TEntity entity)
    {
        await _context.Set<TEntity>().AddAsync(entity);
    }
    ...
}
```

**IUnitOfWork.cs**

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    IGeneralRepository<Report> Reports{ get; }
    ...
}
```

**UnitOfWork.cs**

```
public sealed class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;

    public UnitOfWork(MyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    private IGeneralRepository<Report>_report;
    public IGeneralRepository<Report> Reports => _report ??= new GeneralRepository<MyDbContext, Report>(_context);
    ...
}
```

**ReportService.cs**

```
public class ReportService : GeneralService, IReportService
{
    private readonly IExcelManager _excelManager;

    public ReportService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IExcelManager excelManager)
    {
        UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _excelManager = excelManager;
    }

    public async Task<string> ReportUpload(MemoryStream ms)
    {
        var workingList = _excelManager.ReadExcel(ms);
 
        var i = 0;             
        while (i < workingList.Count)
        {
            var report = new Report { ... }
            await UnitOfWork.Reports.AddAsync(report);
        }

        ....
}
```

**ReportServiceTest.cs**

```
public class ReportServiceTests 
{
    [Fact()]
    public async Task ReportUploadTest()
    {

        //Arrange
        ....
        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Report>>();
        var mockContext = new Mock<MyDbContext>();
        mockContext.Setup(x => x.Reports).Returns(mockSet.Object);

        var reportRepositoryMock = new Mock<IGeneralRepository<Report>>();
        reportRepositoryMock.Setup(m => m.AddAsync(It.IsAny<Report>()));

        var unitOfWorkMock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
        unitOfWorkMock.Setup(p => p.Reports)
            .Returns(reportRepositoryMock.Object);

       ...
       //Act
       var reportService = new ReportService(unitOfWorkMock.Object,exelManagerMock.Object);
       await reportService.ReportUpload(new MemoryStream());

       //Assert
       ???
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

DbContext cannot be passed to the UnitOfWork object because its context field is private.

I had to use SQLite in memory to test the GeneralRepository method.

```
var exelManagerMock = new Mock<IExcelManager>();
        exelManagerMock.Setup(p => p.ReadExcel(It.IsAny<MemoryStream>()))
            .Returns(listOfExcelReadResult);    
var dbFixture = new DatabaseFixture();
var context = dbFixture.CreateContext();

var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(context);
//I need some plus data  
await unitOfWork.Providers.AddRangeAsync(providers);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();

var reportService = new ReportService(unitOfWork, exelManagerMock.Object);
await reportService.ReportUpload(new MemoryStream(), 2021);

var allReports = await reportService.UnitOfWork.Reports.GetAsync();
Assert.Equal(3, allReports.Count);
```